# JSQL to JPQL, how to join in JPQL

Tags: mysql, sql, hibernate, jpql

I've been struggling to understand how joins work in JPQL.
I have the following Sql query I'd like to convert to JPQL:

```
SELECT e.id FROM Workers e 
 JOIN workerJobTypes r ON e.id=r.workerId 
    JOIN jobtypes d ON r.jobTypeId=d.id 
JOIN workerlocations l ON e.id=l.workerId 
   JOIN location t ON l.locatieId=t.id 
WHERE t.id=:locationId AND d.id=:jobTypeId
```

Workers, JobTypes and Location are entity tables, workerlocations and workerjobtypes are join tables. The result should be a Worker object.

Comment: What matters is the entities, not the tables. JPQL works with entities, their fields and their associations. Not with tables. The documentation has a chapter about HQL, with a section dedicated to joins: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/manual/en-US/html_single/#queryhql-joins